# Could the origin of "gangway" as an interjection be from Cantonese?

Tags: etymology, slang

The use of "Gangway!" to tell people to get out of the way seems to be relatively recent (e.g. 100 years) in use.

There is a common equivalent expression in Cantonese, pronounced something like "Gwan-soy!".

Is there any evidence that the English term might simply be a mispronunciation of this Cantonese expression, perhaps as heard by naval or merchant marine seamen in Hong Kong?

This would be the same as how "Bombay", as a similar sounding English word, became the Anglicized version of "Mumbai" (or variations thereof).

Another example would be the French "*chaise longue*", meaning "long chair", which has become Anglicized as "*chaise lounge*".  "Lounge" is a completely different English word, but it sounds similar to the French word for "long" and it's meaning fits well with the use of this furniture.

Inspired by: [Meaning of 滾水 as Cantonese idiom - Chinese Language Stack Exchange](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/40348/meaning-of-%e6%bb%be%e6%b0%b4-as-cantonese-idiom)

Comment: "Gangway" as a term for a passageway has uses going back to the 1700s, at least.

Comment: As an interjection in English, the proper spelling is "Gang way!" It means "Get out of the way!" See https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/gang-way

Comment: Right.  And as two separate words it matches the mispronunciation of  the two word Cantonese expression even better.

Comment: @rhetorician: the first usages of *gangway* in this sense were all one word. And as far as I can tell, there's no etymological reason to spell it with two words. The dictionary you cite also [gives](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/gangway) the one-word spelling, so it's just asserting that two spellings exist, not that one of them is "correct".

Comment: @PeterShor: We may need to agree to disagree, agreeably, on this one, Peter. As an interjection, "Gang way!" is perfectly acceptable, and it means to get ready for the imminent arrival of something great or imposing.  "Make room on the gangway for the debarking of the passengers" is also perfectly acceptable. In other words, make room for the passengers who are making their way down the external staircase/walkway from the ship to the dock.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that there   is no evidence of a possible origin from Cantonese. ***[Gangway](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gangway)*** has its roots in Old English **gangweg** "road, passage, thoroughfare”.

> temporary passageway" to a ship, building under construction, etc., ultimately from Old English gangweg "road, passage, thoroughfare;" a compound of [gang](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gang?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_1264) (n.) in its original sense "a going, journey, way, passage" and way (n.).

(Etymonline)

Comment: Yes, I'm not questioning the origins of the word "gangway" itself.  It's only the use of that English word's pronunciation applied to a completely different meaning foreign word that I'm wondering about.  See my recently added French "*longue*" (meaning "lounge") which has been Anglicized as "lounge".  There's no suggestion that the ordinary English word "lounge" originated from the French word "longue", except in this one specific usage.

Comment: @RayButterworth I think your question needs to be clearer, then. *Gangway* is not related to the Cantonese expression etymologically, and although some corrupted Cantonese words do make it into English (such as *char* for *tea*), the fact that *gangway* is actually an Old English word makes it unlikely here. You have your answer, unless you have asked the wrong question.